# Text size changes within a \displaystyle environment?

Tags: math-mode, memoir, superscripts

I am trying to get some equations for an exercise down. However with a fraction in the exponent it gets rather hard to read, that's why I wanted to play around with font sizes ... with rather disappointing results. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent   $ 4^{\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle  4^{\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $4^{\dfrac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle {\Huge 4}^{\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle {\Huge 4}^{\dfrac{3}{2}}$ \\
\end{document}
```

leads to
[image: a rather strange result]

So I am looking for a way to increase the size of the base 4, just to give myself a little more room for crazier exponents.

Comment: Maybe `4^{3/2}` is an option?

Comment: the last two are in error: you can not use a size command like \huge in math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697487/128801), that it seems to be a problem with the math environment I found a workaround with the `\text{}` command within a math environment.

```
$8^{\frac{3}{2}} \implies \text{\huge $8$}^{\frac{3}{2}}$
```

produces [image: this result] which also works with everything else inside the math-environment in the text environment.

Comment: yes `\text`  is your friend if you really need size changes here

Comment: I would try \begin{Huge}4\end{Huge} otherwise I think it doesn't know when to stop making the text huge.

Comment: since `\huge` is inside `\text{}` it get's only used inside this environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use size commands within the math, but you can locally increase the size of the expression or adjust the notation to not require subscripted fractions. Depending on the context I'd use one of the last three here, less likely to use one of the first three, but they are possibilities.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent   $ 4^{\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle  4^{\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle  4^{\textstyle\frac{3}{2}}$ \\
    $\displaystyle  4^{3/2}$ \\
   {\large     $\displaystyle  4^{\frac{3}{2}}$}\\
    $8$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, maybe I need more of a workaround then. It should be an exercise sheet for my german students (9th grade, the first time they are confronted with the rational exponent) ... the last answer is what the students should figure out, but since the text book doesn't use notations like `3/2` or a `/nicefrac` that might lead to a whole new level of missunderstandings. But your comment gave me an idea that works in THIS specific case: `$\text{\huge 8}^{\frac{3}{2}}$`solves my problem.

Comment: I am not able to edit the previous comment any more ... but your answer got me thinking and I found a solution that seems to work. Since I am relatively new to this and my solution is based on your answer, which one should I tag as "this solves my problem"?

Comment: @Sk1nk accept the answer you used. If you don't accept mine I don't get 15 points, but to be honest I have more than enough points already and I won't lose any sleep if I don't get 15 more:-)